# Which is the better way of loading bitmap for multiple screen size

Tags: android

I'm making a free educational alphabet activity app for kinder gardeners. There will be one image for each alphabet covering nearly 90% width and 75% height of the screen.. Android developer reference points out that we can put different sized image for different sized screen. That means I'll have 26 * 4 images and in future if I put more than one image for each alphabet there will be 26 * 4 * x images which will drastically increase the app size.

Instead of this I'm thinking of using one big sized image that is near to  Nexus 10 resolution re sizing it according to screen size in the application itself. Is this the better way?

Also does the image size need to match nearly the Nexus 10 resolution to make it appear nice on Nexus 10 itself?

Comment: That will make the apk size bloated for phone sized devices.

Answer (score 1):

Adding multiple image versions into your project, is meant to help you to **optimize** your app for every device. 
This can cause, like you are experiencing, problems with APK size and you should wonder what the real important thing is here for you.

First of all you can probably pull it off just fine to only add XHDPI images for phones, and bigger images in -xlarge for tablets.

This gets you going for most phones and tablets with a reasonable amount of re-using images and thus probably APK size.
If you want to support per exapmle the Nexus10, you'll have to add images for that which are pretty much only used for the Nexus 10 itself at the moment.

Basically the point is, you have to decide yourself how important it is for you to support all devices perfectly. Are those kids really going to notice? Do they even have a Nexus 10?

Furthermore, you can always package multiple APKs. So you could simply build multiple APKs, which only contain the set of images once, and via the manifest restrict them to certain devices (dpi and size).